# Seo URL - htacces rewrite rules

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite some urls:

In php they are designed like: `www.example.com/product.php?id=1`

Someone helped me to rewrite them to: `www.example.com/product/1/casual-shoe/`

Now I found that is not recommended for SEO.

And I need to transform the link in something like:

```
www.example.com/casual-shoe/ShoeNickname`
```

I don't know from where to begin.

I will make in mysql a new column for `ShoeNickname` equivalent to each id.

Is there anyone who can tell me how to write the `.htacces` file?

Comment: Where did you see that "is not recommended for SEO"?

Comment: It's not good for link structure - it's better not to have so many folders.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in this example `casual-shoe' is the category and you sell many casual shoes.

The easiest was to solve this is to keep id in the URL, while ignoring the other information, like www.example.com/casual-shoe/23-converse-all-stars

The .htaccess would be something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+/(\d+)-.*$ /product.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The 2 RewriteCond lines tell to only rewrite if the requested url doesn't match a real file. Next you rewrite anything with a (category) directory followed by a filename starting with 1 or more decimals, followed by a dash and more text.

The decimals are the product ID, the rest of the URL is simply ignored.

Comment: Thank you for your answere, i will try it right now. Can you tell me a virtaul source where i can learn to write htacces?

Comment: Is working grate, but my boss will surely want to hide that number from there... can you lead me somewhere where i can read and solve that problem too?

Comment: That would require adding a reference field to the database, making sure the reference is unique while saving and looking up the reference. The exact code is beyond a simple answer on Stackoverflow. I would try to convince your boss to use the above solution. Having the number in there doesn't have any negative consequences for SEO.